# How to split a dataframe column into multiple columns with a Pandas converter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with rows like this:

```
blablabla (CODE1513A15), 9.20, 9.70, 0
```

I want pandas to read each column, but from the first column I am interested only in the data between brackets, and I want to extract it into additional columns. Therefore, I tried using a Pandas converter:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import string

code = 'CODE'
code_parser = lambda x: {
    'date': datetime(int(x.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0][len(code):len(code)+2]), string.uppercase.index(x.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0][len(code)+4:len(code)+5])+1, int(x.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0][len(code)+2:len(code)+4])), 
    'value': float(x.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0].split('-')[0][len(code)+5:])
}
column_names = ['first_column', 'second_column', 'third_column', 'fourth_column']
pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3], names=column_names, converters={'first_column': code_parser})
```

With this code, I can convert the text between brackets to a dict containing a datetime object and a value.

If the code is CODE1513A15 as in the sample, it will be built from:

- a known code (in this example, 'CODE')
- two digits for the year
- two digits for the day of month
- A letter from A to L, which is the month (A for January, B for February, ...)
- A float value

I tested the lambda function and it correctly extracts the information I want, and its output is a dict `{'date': datetime(15, 1, 13), 'value': 15}`. Nevertheless, if I print the result of the `pd.read_csv` method, the 'first_column' is a dict, while I was expecting it to be replaced by two columns called 'date' and 'value':

```
                         first_column  second_column  third_column  fourth_column
0   {u'date':13-01-2015, u'value':15}           9.20          9.70              0
1   {u'date':14-01-2015, u'value':16}           9.30          9.80              0
2   {u'date':15-01-2015, u'value':12}           9.40          9.90              0
```

What I want to get is:

```
               date  value  second_column  third_column  fourth_column
0        13-01-2015     15           9.20          9.70              0
1        14-01-2015     16           9.30          9.80              0
2        15-01-2015     12           9.40          9.90              0
```

Note: I don't care how the date is formatted, this is only a representation of what I expect to get.

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my original comment because it no longer felt relevant... It turns out I can't reproduce your problem with Python 3. I get a dataframe with a first_column containing this dict: `{'date': 0015-01-13 00:00:00, 'value': 15.0}`.

Comment: @IanS That is also happening using Python 2.7: I was looking only at the end of the output, but it was being split in two parts since I have more columns that those shown in the example. I will update the question now. Anyway, I was expecting the "first_column" to be replaced by two columns called "date" and "value", not "first_column" being a dict. I can live with this, but I would prefer to split the columns. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You're probably better off processing the data in pandas after reading the CSV file as is.

Comment: @IanS could you provide an example for that? Pandas newbie here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's better to do things step by step.

```
# read data into a data frame
column_names = ['first_column', 'second_column', 'third_column', 'fourth_column']
df = pd.read_csv(data, names=column_names)

# extract values using regular expression which is much more robust
# than string spliting
tmp = df.first_column.str.extract('CODE(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-L]{1})(\d+)')
tmp.columns = ['year', 'day', 'month', 'value']
tmp['month'] = tmp['month'].apply(lambda m: str(ord(m) - 64))
```

Sample output:

```
print tmp 
  year day month value
0   15  13     1    15
```

Then transform your original data frame into the format that you want

```
df['date'] = (tmp['year'] + tmp['day'] + tmp['month']).apply(lambda d: strptime(d, '%y%d%m'))
df['value'] = tmp['value']
del df['first_column']
```

Answer (score 2):

Is conversion in the `read_csv` is mandatory? Otherwise, passing a function which returns `Series` to `apply` results in `DataFrame`.

```
df 
              first_column  second_column  third_column  fourth_column
0  blablabla (CODE1513A15)            9.2           9.7              0
1  blablabla (CODE1514A16)            9.2           9.7              0

code_parser = lambda x: pd.Series({
    'date': datetime(2000+int(x.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0][len(code):len(code)+2]), string.uppercase.index(x.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0][len(code)+4:len(code)+5])+1, int(x.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0][len(code)+2:len(code)+4])), 
    'value': float(x.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0].split('-')[0][len(code)+5:])
})

df['first_column'].apply(code_parser)
        date  value
0 2015-01-13     15
1 2015-01-14     16
```